# App crashes when scrolling on UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on an app and one of the views is a UICollectionView. I have gotten the collection view to work totally fine. When the user presses on one of the collection view cells, a new view opens with a photo. However, the app crashes when I try to scroll on the collection view.

Here's my code:

```
let cellMapArray = [UIImage(named: "pomona.jpg"), UIImage(named: "Pitzer.jpg"), UIImage(named: "Mudd.jpg"), UIImage(named: "Scripps.jpg"), UIImage(named: "CMC1.jpg")]


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return self.schoolNames.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

    cell.imageView?.image = self.cellMapArray[indexPath.row]

    cell.imageTitle?.text = self.schoolNames[indexPath.row]

    return cell

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showImage", sender: self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
{
    if segue.identifier == "showImage"
    {
        let indexPaths = self.collectionView!.indexPathsForSelectedItems!
        let indexPath = indexPaths[0] as IndexPath
        let vc = segue.destination as! NewViewController
        vc.image = self.mapArray[indexPath.row]!
        vc.title = self.schoolNames[indexPath.row]
    }
}
```

And the line that is highlighted when the app crashes is:

```
 cell.imageView?.image = self.cellMapArray[indexPath.row]
```

The error I get is

> fatal error: Index out of range (lldb)." And the line of code is highlighted with the error "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_l386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Using multiple arrays as data source is error-prone. The error occurs If the number of items in `schoolNames` and `cellMapArray` are not equal. Use a custom class or struct to avoid that kind of error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error states, the **indexPath.row** value is not in the bounds of the array **cellMapArray**. Make sure that the **cellMapArray** has enough elements in the array, so that the array has an element at the index **indexPath.row**